# Aligning CSS transforms

Tags: html, css

so I have been relearning html/css and ASP.NET MVC and I'm having trouble putting the finishing touches on a navbar.  The following produces a side navbar that transforms when hovered over:

html:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
            <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Index", "Services")</li>
            <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Index", "Contact")</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

css:

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 7vw;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    transition: 1s;}

.menu:hover {
    width: 40vw;
}

.menu:hover ~ .container {
    transform: perspective(80vw) rotateY(10deg) translateX(35vw) scaleY(1.2);
}

.menu:hover nav {
    left: 20%;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50%;
    left: -1000px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.nav-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50vh;
    margin-left: 30%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 35px solid #569cbd;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}

.nav-list {
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-item {
    line-height: 3em;
    letter-spacing: .3em;
}

a {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

I don't know if I have been staring at it for too long or what, but I cannot get the .nav-arrow to align with the menu transform.  Thanks for any and all advice!

Comment: As the `.nav-arrow` is positioned `absolute` you must add a `relative` div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adding `right: 48px;` (or similiar) to `.nav-arrow` does the work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do but if you want the `.nav-arrow` to stay right aligned as the pink menu bar opens update the the `.nav-arrow` code to use `right: 0` rather than a margin as below:

```
.nav-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 50vh;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 35px solid #569cbd;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}
```

```css
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 7vw;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    transition: 1s;}

.menu:hover {
    width: 40vw;
}

.menu:hover ~ .container {
    transform: perspective(80vw) rotateY(10deg) translateX(35vw) scaleY(1.2);
}

.menu:hover nav {
    left: 20%;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50%;
    left: -1000px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.nav-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 50vh;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 35px solid #569cbd;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}

.nav-list {
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-item {
    line-height: 3em;
    letter-spacing: .3em;
}

a {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-item">Home</li>
            <li class="nav-item">About</li>
            <li class="nav-item">Services</li>
            <li class="nav-item">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```